# Explicit Euler or implicit Euler for $\dot{y}=\begin{pmatrix} -600 & 400 \\ 400 & -600 \end{pmatrix}y$, $t\in[t_0,t_e]$, $y(t_0) = y_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes

I'm asked **to decide** if I should solve the system
$$\dot{y}=\begin{pmatrix}
-600 & 400 \\
400 & -600
\end{pmatrix}y, \quad t\in[t_0,t_e], \quad y(t_0) = y_0$$
with **either** the explicit Euler method or the implicit Euler method.

Using the explicit Euler method I would get the updating scheme
$$y_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1-600h & 400h \\
400h & 1-600h
\end{pmatrix}y_n$$
where the eigenvalues of the driving matrix is 
$$\lambda_1 = 401-600h,$$
$$\lambda_2 = -399 - 600h.$$
For the solution to be stable these need to be less than one which gives the conditions
$$h\geq\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3},$$
$$h\geq -\frac{4}{6}=-\frac{2}{3}.$$
The last condition doesn't say anything but the first condition seems restrictive since I can't choose $h$ as small as possible.

If I instead were to use the implicit Euler method I would get the updating scheme
$$y_{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1-600h & 400h \\
400h & 1-600h
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}y_n.$$
Now I can't solve for the eigenvalues of this system but I've heard the implicit Euler is unconditionally stable so it shouldn't matter.

So is the answer that I should choose implicit Euler because it is unconditionally stable or am I missing something? The order of consistency of both is $1$ so that should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of eigenvalues is wrong. Of the system matrix in $y'=Ay$ there is one eigenvalue $-200$ with eigenvector $\pmatrix{1\\1}$ and one eigenvalue $-1000$ with eigenvector $\pmatrix{1\\-1}$. These translate into eigenvalues $1-200h$ and $1-1000h$ of the "driving matrix" for the Euler method, requiring $h<0.002$ for stability.

For the implicit method there are no step size restrictions to get stability in the method, to get into the range where the error behaves like order 1 one still will need $500h\ll 1$.

Comment: Ah shit used $400$ instead of $400h$ in the eigenvalue calculation. So the conclusion is that even though the order of consistency of both methods is 1, the explicit euler will require **significantly** more computations, in comparison to implicit euler, to achieve that?

Comment: Yes and no. If you measure accuracy, then both methods require about the same step size, within a factor of perhaps 2, to get similar errors. If you only care about the quantitative behavior, that the solution rapidly converges to zero, then the A-stability of implicit Euler allows much larger step sizes.